# Is IMvxLocationWatcher incompatible after recent update?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am writing an app with Xamarin.Android and MvvmCross. My app is using Google's map service to draw the map of the current location using GPS. I am using `IMvxLocationWatcher` to do so. Everything was working fine until I updated all of my nuget packages today, and now it throws an exception on this line:

```
_locationWatcher.Start(options, OnLocationFound, OnLocationNotFound);
```

Exception:

> System.MissingMethodException: Method 'Android.Gms.Common.Zze.IsGooglePlayServicesAvailable' not found.

I tried both the emulator and physical device. I'm guessing that there was an update to Google's Android libraries for the map, that has rendered it incompatible with MvvmCross (for now at least). Is there a fix for this or a temporary workaround?

Comment: Which version of MvvmCross are you using? Are you using the Fused Location plugin or the Location plugin?

Comment: The Location plugin with the MvvmCross (5.6.3)

Comment: It seems like you are using Fused Location plugin in your Android project because the old Location plugin wouldn't contain any references to `IsGooglePlayServicesAvailable`. Did you by any chance update the Google Play Services NuGet from 42.1021.1 to 60.1142.0 right before you noticed the problem?

Comment: Yes I did, I actually updated all my nuget packages all at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fused Location Plugin requires Google Play Services version 42.1021.1 with MvvmCross 5.6.3. You can update to Google Play Service 60.1142.0 when you upgrade to MvvmCross 6.0. MvvmCross 6.0 is currently in beta. Revert the Google Play Services NuGet libraries back to 42.1021.1 to fix the problem.